# Select by tag from different table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

images
id | …

keyword_relations
id | keyword_id | image_id

keywords
id | keyword

How do I select if someone search for something like 'house'. And how can I show only images with all keywords when searching for multiple keywords like 'red house' (keyword 'red' and keyword 'house').

The queries that I have doesn't work perfectly and some of them are pretty slow.

Is this even possible in one query or would it be better to split them?

Comment: Assuming the number of keywords can vary, one way to do this is to use string concatenation to build the SQL. If that's not what you meant, please provide more specific example data. Does the order matter or the keywords can appear in any order?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far, so we can work from that.

Comment: I just fiddled around with different approachs but none of them seems like a good solution. I thought because this is a pretty common table structure for informations like this there have to be some kind of best practice that im unaware of …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested here what i have so far (simplified). First i from keywords the ids by keyword (search string exploded):
`"SELECT id FROM keywords WHERE keyword IN($keywords)"`

From that i generate a list of ids which is used for the main query:
`"SELECT i.* FROM images i JOIN keyword_relations k ON k.image_id = i.id WHERE k.keyword_id IN($kids) GROUP BY i.id HAVING COUNT( k.keyword_id ) = $keywordcount"`

The COUNT can even be used to order by relevance, were relevance is the number of matching keywords.